# Как разрешить http трафик, а так же изменить все http запроса на https в Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, apache

Всем привет! имею две проблемы. Выгрузил свой проект на сервер(apache). Подключил cloudfare, подключил ssl. Теперь сайт находится на https. И тут пошли ошибки:

1) К примеру есть форма, в `action` указываю `{{route('action')}}`, и этот роут переносит на `http`, и вылазит такая ошибка `Заблокирована загрузка смешанного активного содержимого «http://`
, но если в `action` указывать обычный путь, то есть `/action`, то запрос будет проходить через `https`, так вот, как исправить, чтоб именованный роут шел через `https`? Это только происходит с рутами, когда я указываю их имя в пути, как тут: `<form action="{{route('name_route')}}"></form>` или когда использую `axios` запрос и в `Url` указываю `{{route('name_route')}}`. То есть такие руты используют `http` протокол, а нужно `https`.

2) На сайте подключен скрипт, который идет только по `http` протоколу, а у меня сайт находится на `https` протоколе. И этот скрипт отказывается работать из-за этого. Как сделать, чтоб сервер пропускал этот скрипт?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) В .env (лежит в корне папки) поменяйте значение APP_URL с http на https

```
APP_URL=https://example.com
```

2) Загрузка скрипта с "небезопасным" http внутри защищенного (https) сайта полностью нарушает безопасность сайта. Поэтому вряд ли получится просто так вот взять и грузить из "небезопасной" зоны. Простейшее решение - перенесите этот скрипт на свой сайт, если это возможно. Если нет, то ищите альтернативы.